# How to update a form input when another input changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have a simple form that allows the user to select an item.  When that item is selected, I want to update the SalePriceEach input to the default price of the item they selected.  All required data (a collection of all items) is available in the view's ViewBag.  I've found [this](https://damienbod.com/2018/07/08/updating-part-of-an-asp-net-core-mvc-view-which-uses-forms/) example that uses partial views, but that seems rather excessive for a simple value update.  The validation options (Remote and client side) don't seem to be the right tools.  I could manage it with Javascript but that feels like it would defeat the purpose of some asp.net core feature. My view is below - any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
@model My.Stuff.Server.Models.QuoteItem

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add To Quote";
}

<h2>Add Item to Quote</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quote.QuoteNumber)</dt>
            <dd> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Quote.QuoteNumber)    </dd>
            <dt> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quote.QuoteId)   </dt>
            <dd> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Quote.QuoteId)       </dd>
        </dl>
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <input class="hidden" asp-for="QuoteId" />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger</div>
            <div class="form-group">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Item.PartNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ItemId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofItems,"ItemId","PartNumber"))"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ItemId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SalePriceEach" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SalePriceEach" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SalePriceEach" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

**Update**: I've implemented a solution with Javascript as shown below, but I feel like there should be an asp.net implementation of this.  Razor syntax is used to initialize the data array listofItems.

```
<script>
    var listOfItems = [];     
    $(function () {
        function UpdatePrice(idString) {
            var $price = $("#SalePriceEach");
            var id = parseInt(idString, 10);
            var match = listOfItems.filter(function (element) {
                return element.id == id;
            });
            if (match.length > 0) $price.val(match[0].price);
            else $price.val("999,999");
        }

        listOfItems.push({ 'id':1, 'price':3.4 });                
        listOfItems.push({ 'id':2, 'price':2.456 });
        $("#ItemId").on('change', function (e) {
            UpdatePrice($(this).val())
        });
        UpdatePrice($("#ItemId").val());
    });
</script>
```

**Solution** that I settled on was to query all the items from the database (_context) within the model controller and then send this query to the ViewBag as follows:

```
public IActionResult Create(long? id) 
{
    ItemChild q = new ItemChild() { ItemParentId = id ?? -1, Qty = 1};
    ViewBag.ListofItems = _context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemId != ItemParentId);
    return View(q);
}
```

Then show a select control containing a list of these items in the view with:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Item.PartNumber" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="ItemId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofItems,"ItemId","PartNumber"))"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="ItemId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add all the necessary codes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible using jQuery 
put ids for every input type for short hand usage 
like

```
     <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" id="Quantity"/>
 <input asp-for="SalePriceEach" class="form-control" id="SalePriceEach"/>
```

using Jquery text change function

```
jQuery('#Quantity').on('input', function() {
//take value of Quantity input
var v1=$("#Quantity").val();
//then assigne this value to another input 
$("#SalePriceEach").val(v1)
   });
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was any specific features of asp.net that should be used for this purpose.  I would like to avoid rendering all values and then employing JQuery or Javascript (unless that is the most straightforward solution).